# using Ext JS with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

I am a newbie to Ext JS, but I want to use Ext JS with ruby on rails.
Can anyone tell me what I am supposed to do?
Are there any plugins needed ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m using Ext js with Php and Java web, all you have to do is import the library and use it. make what you want with ext js and call GET/POST to your site's uri as usual and pass datas via xml or json(i prefer json,because it's easier).

Eg. ext capture button press -> GET/POST a uri -> controller process -> do whatever in model ->send json data back -> ext decode json-> display to user

Answer (score 2):

I never tried it, but have a look at http://netzke.org/.

Answer (score 2):

You can get some basics from http://www.extjswithrails.com/. I am sure that will help you get started. Here is also an old tutorial on Sencha site: [Using Ext Grid with Ruby on Rails](http://ww.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial%3aUsing_Ext_Grid_with_Ruby_on_Rails)

But apart from that, you will have to go through ExtJS API documentation and its examples. Reading Sencha example's code can really help you in coding.